# Shred script with output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to write a shred script to output the files deleted to text file but I think I'm doing something wrong with the output? I was also thinking of adding a email section to the script to email confirmation when all files have been deleted but first things first need to get the output working to a text file.

Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash

# Use on remote server

LOCATION="/home/user/Test"
TIMES=-n38

cd $LOCATION

# Delete all files in location 30 times

echo "Deleting all delete located at $LOCATION "

nohup find $LOCATION -exec shred $TIMES -u '{}' \; & >> /home/user/output.txt

echo "All data at $LOCATION has been shredded $TIMES times"

# Delete the partition

#nohup shred -n 30 -vz /dev/sdb1 &
```

Comment: Or add "wait" somewhere in your script.

Comment: Or you might want to remove the space after ''&''. ''&>>'' makes sense, but ''& >>'' does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ampersand needs to be at the end of the command, after the stdout redirection:

```
nohup find $LOCATION -exec shred $TIMES -u '{}' \; >> /home/user/output.txt &
```

Answer (score 0):

`&` places the process in the background; so using it between the shell command isn't the way to go...

Try moving it towards the end...

```
nohup <your shell command> &
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Add `-print` option to `find` command, e.g.

```
find $LOCATION -print -exec shred $TIMES -u '{}' \;
```

2) As others have already pointed out, move ampersand to the end

3) Shouldn't `shred $TIMES` be `shred -n $TIMES`?